# How to invoke Z3 on an input file

Tags: z3

I have a file containing:

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Real)
(declare-const e Real)
(assert (> a (+ b 2)))
(assert (= a (+ (* 2 c) 10)))
(assert (<= (+ c b) 1000))
(assert (>= d e))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and, according to the online tutorial, running z3 on this file should return:

```
sat
(model
    (define-fun c () Int
        (- 5))
    (define-fun a () Int
        0)
    (define-fun b () Int
        (- 3))
    (define-fun d ()
        Real 0.0)
    (define-fun e ()
        Real 0.0)
)
```

So I know this is legal Z3 input.  However, whenever I run "z3 [option] " all I get is error messages no matter what option I choose -- including none.  Can someone tell me how to correctly invoke Z3 on the input file?

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Z3 supports many input formats. It uses the file extension to guess which parser will be used. If the extension is `.smt2`. It will use the SMT 2.0 parser. You can also specify which parser should be used. The option `-smt2` will force Z3 to use the SMT 2.0 parser. Finally, Z3 does not enable model construction by default. So, you should use the option `MODEL=true`, or add the command `(set-option :produce-models true)` in the beginning of your script.

If you want to use a very old version of Z3, you will have to use SMT 1.0 format.
This format is described at: http://goedel.cs.uiowa.edu/smtlib/papers/format-v1.2-r06.08.30.pdf

That being said, I strongly encourage you to upgrade. The SMT 1.0 is not very user friendly, and most documentation/tutorials for SMT are in SMT 2.0 format.

Here is your example in this format:

```
(benchmark file
  :extrafuns ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int) (d Real) (e Real))
  :assumption (> a (+ b 2))
  :assumption (= a (+ (* 2 c) 10))
  :assumption (<= (+ c b) 1000)
  :assumption (>= d e)
  :formula true)
```

Comment: I added (set-option :produce-models true) at the beginning of my script but all of the parsing options still produce only error messages.  In particular -smt2 is an unrecognized option (I'm using version 2.3 if that helps).  What parser is appropriate for the input file I have shown?

Comment: This file is in SMT 2.0 format. Z3 2.3 is a really old version. It does not even support SMT 2.0. You should download the latest version 3.2 at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/download.html

Comment: Unfortunately this is a school assignment and I am forced to use whatever version is installed on the university lab.

Comment: I updated the answer. I added your example in SMT 1.0 format.